# confusion on how to generate the pie chart from the data I have in d3

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

Hi I have been looking at the Pie Chart generation in the d3 and I found that most of the data set were something along the line of

> Data = [ {grade: “A”, number: 20},  {grade: “B”, number: 12},  {grade:
>   “C”, number: 15}];

But I have data like this:

> Data = [ domain1: 0, domain2: 1, domain3: 0, domain4: 1, domain5: 0,
>   domain6: 1];

And I want to represent this as a pie chart where 50% is occupied by domain2 and another 50% is occupied by domain4 ie. for everyone 1 entry in the domain I want it to be a part of the pie chart.

but I am not sure how to use Pie function from d3 in this situation so any suggestions? 
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why is 50% domain2 and 50% domain4?  What happened to domain6?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert your data into an appropriate format for `d3.pie` to use. Your data is already in sort of an object type format:

```
var input = { domain1: 10, domain2: 3, domain3: 6, domain4: 8, domain5: 12, domain6: 13 };
```

To use it with d3.pie, you want either an array or an array of objects. In this case, an array of objects might be simplest:

```
var data = Object.keys(input).map( function(d) { return {name: d, value: input[d]}; } );
```

That turns your original input into an array of the form

```
[{ name: 'domain1', value: 10 }, { name: 'domain2', value: 3 }, ...
```

The [documentation for d3.pie](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#pies) has full details on the configuration options, but for a basic chart, just set the accessor so that d3.pie knows where to get the value for each pie slice:

```
var pie = d3.pie()
            .value(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

and then you need to call

```
pie(data)
```

to generate the appropriate pie layout.

Here's an example with a slightly more interesting version of your data plugged into [some standard pie chart code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c"]);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var input = { domain1: 10, domain2: 3, domain3: 6, domain4: 8, domain5: 12, domain6: 13 };

var data = Object.keys(input).map( function(d) { return {name: d, value: input[d]}; } );

  var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
    .data( pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  arc.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

  arc.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```